# React JS Why does sessionStorage.getItem fail to read token value passed from another page?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api

I have a login page that accepts a username and password; the page consumes a json/API that generates a token when the username and password is entered and submitted. 
My goal is to pass the token from the **Login page** to a **Landing page** that displays the user's respective data based off of the token.

The issue am encountering is, in my fetch clause of the **Landing page**, the token is not getting passed, which results in an "unexpected end of json" error.

code snippet from Landing Page:

```
componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://myapiclient:11111/api/clients', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +sessionStorage.getItem('token')
            },
        })
        .then(results => results.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ data: data }))
    }
```

...The issue appears to occur on this line:

```
'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +sessionStorage.getItem('token')
```

...I confirmed via the chrome console, when noticing that a blank object was being returned. Now when I copy the token from the console and manually paste it into the same line, for e.g.:

```
'Authorization': 'Bearer 11111.22222.555555'
```

...my Landing page displays the client's data (no errors) and the token I copied and pasted into the code snippet provided above renders the token to the console.

One other thing, I also performed a console.log in the rendering section of the Landing page: 
console.log("The client token:" +sessionStorage.token);  ...and confirmed that the token is being passed from the Login page, but the line of code I provided above is not capturing the token.

Below, I provided a url to the full code:
**Login Page**: 
https://codepen.io/lkennedy009/pen/mLKPLv?editors=0010#0

**Landing Page**: 
https://codepen.io/lkennedy009/pen/ELRKpw?editors=0010#0

...could I please get some help as to what I'm doing wrong? I reviewed the syntax /concept in regards to both session and local storage, but still can't seem to determine what it is am doing wrong.

Comment: can you try with es6 syntax like 'Authorization': `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem('token')}`. `(this is back ticks)

Comment: If the second page has a different URL the session `Object` will be different to.